# asp.net bootstrap modal - redirect after close

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, redirect, bootstrap-modal

my Bootstrap modal works fine but I can't find a way to redirect to another page after clicking the "Close" button in the modal.
My javascript :

```
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/css/myStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Head" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() { 
        $("#btnBS_Modal").click();
    }
</script>
```

My HTML :

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnBS_Modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myBS_Modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            Launch demo modal</button>
        <div class="modal fade in" id="myBS_Modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBS_Modal" runat="server"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code behind :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
this.lblBS_Modal.Text = "This is some message";
Response.Redirect("~/aaa.aspx");
```

The "Respose.Redirect" takes me to the proper page, but the modal is not popping up at all.
Searched a lot but couldn't get an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the great and mighty @mason I finally got it to work.
My MasterPage:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Redirect - <%: Page.Title %></title>
    <script src="/Content/Scripts/myJavaScripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/myStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
```

Notice that the FIRST link is to "myJavaScripts.js" where I put the js which is:

```
function ShowPopup() {
    $("#btnBS_Modal").click();
    $('#myBS_Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var url = $("#RedirectUrlHf").val();
        window.location = url;
    });
}
```

In the HTML of the page where the Modal is, I have :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="RedirectUrlHf" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnBS_Modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myBS_Modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                Launch demo modal</button>
            <div class="modal fade in" id="myBS_Modal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBS_Modal" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

(Notice the hiddenfield which needs to have `ClientIDMode="Static"`).

In my code behind :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RedirectUrlHf.Value = ResolveUrl("/Account/aaa.aspx");
    }
```

Now when the modal on my page closes, I am redirected to the proper page.
@mason was a great help and I learned a lot from him on the way. Thank you, @mason.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the difference between client code and server code. Server code runs through to completion, the resulting markup is sent to the client, then the client side code runs. So popping up a modal from server side code, followed by a redirect, isn't going to work. It's going to redirect the client, and the client will never execute any markup because the redirect is performed immediately.

Instead, you need to use client side code to handle the [bootstrap modal closing event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) and perform the redirect.

```
$('#myBS_Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/aaa.aspx")>';
});
```

---

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() { 
        $("#btnBS_Modal").click();
    }        
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() { 
        $("#btnBS_Modal").click();
    }
    $('#myBS_Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/aaa.aspx") %>';
    });
</script>
```

and get rid of your server side code that performs the redirect.

---

Since you can't use inline code, try this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="RedirectUrlHf" ClientIdMode="static" />

  /* Inside your script tag */
 $('#myBS_Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      var url =  $("#RedirectUrlHf").val();
      window.location = url;
    });
```

And on Page_Load, add this.

```
RedirectUrlHf.Value = ResolveUrl("~/aaa.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to JS and I can't find the proper way to implement your suggestion. I will now edit my question so as to show the full "head" section of my HTML. Please tell me where exectly to place your code.  Thanks again.

Comment: @gadi Updated answer.

Comment: That's what I first tried, but it messes up the whole HTML and throws so many error, like "the head element is missing its closing tag" and more.  There's something wrong with the syntax and I'm now trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: @gadi I've updated my answer slightly, realized I was missing a % sign.

Comment: Yes - I noticed that and already added the missing % and the syntax errors were gone but when running it the server says : The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Comment: Ah, that's a combination of issues. Somewhere else you're trying to modify the Controls, and you can't because of the `<%= %>` syntax. What you can do is put the correct URL in a hidden field, then using JavaScript retrieve the value from the hidden field, then redirect to it.

Comment: Will try that (got to check out exactly how...) and will let you know. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: In Page_Load it says : The name 'RedirectUrlHf' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Ah, this is the name of the hidden field. Stupid me....  But it still does not redirect me to aaa.aspx after closing the modal.

Comment: @gadi Check your client side console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: I updated my original question with a solution, but I will look into your idea, find out why it doesn't work for me, and let you know. Cheers.

Comment: @gadi Do not put solutions in the question, post them as an answer. And you need to realize that your solution doesn't map properly against the virtual root. It's dependent on the page you're redirecting to being in the same folder. If you try my solution, it will properly account for that.

Comment: Thanks, mason. But : say my modal is in page "~/Admin/ManageRoles.aspx" and in the Close button of the modal I add : `onclick="window.location = ('/ForAll/About.aspx')"` then I'm redirected properly from a page in one folder to a page in another folder. So please explain why you think this is a wrong solution.

Comment: Because you're not accounting for the difference between absolute root and virtual path root. It might *work* but that doesn't mean it won't blow up in your face later if you switch to hosting as a virtual application, or change the directory structure.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I'll work on your solution and try to figure out why I can't make it work.

Comment: Your code works fine as long as I don't use Master Page. When I do use Master Page, the hidden field is null. I'm investigating that now....

Comment: @gadi Did you make sure to use the `ClientIdMode="static"` property? Without that, the ID of the HTML element will change on the client when a master page gets involved.

Comment: MAN, YOU ROCK !!!!!     Now I will put your code here as a proper answer.   When I grow up (and I'm 62 yo now...) I want to be you!