# .close popup model before redirecting to another page on aspx.cs page

Tags: asp.net, model, popup

[asp.net bootstrap modal - redirect after close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502790/asp-net-bootstrap-modal-redirect-after-close/32531727#32531727)

I need to do same thing but on `aspx.cs` page:

I just need to close model using `asp.net`:

```
CartUrl = "/asp/newviewcart.aspx";  
string script = "window.parent.location.href ='" + CartUrl + "'";
```

I just want to close model before `window.parent.location`.

Comment: my Problem is same as ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502790/asp-net-bootstrap-modal-redirect-after-close/32531727#32531727

Comment: please any one can solve it ....I am novice in .net .. thanks in advance

Comment: My question is something like .......Is it possible to pop-up a window from the code-behind
aspx.cs file on an OnClick event?
If so, how?
I've tried something like the following, but it doesnt seem to work.

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs
e)
{
Response.Write("<script>window.open('mypopUp_dialo g.aspx');<script>");
}

I don't want to use in-line javascript code or use a <script> tag within my
aspx file
itself.

Comment: how to close a popup window model using code behind  aspx.cs